# How to properly encode ATG commerce JSON taglib droplet response

Tags: json, special-characters, jquery-templates, atg, commerce

I had a problem where I was doing an jquery $get for a list of schools. I was using an RQLForeach droplet to retrieve the list and specified the output to be JSON, I would then take the returned JSON and use jQuery template to render out the result.

Problem I was seeing the following in the output `King&#39;s`which should've been King's School.

I used the {{html schoolName}} Which was supposed to take care of the decoding correctly. But it did not....

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem.

Problem: Was that encoding and decoding was happening twice. First the json:object that gets output from the droplet was already escaping XML. So would therefore encode the & of the apostrophe. i.e. it was reaching client side as
`&amp#39;` instead of `&#39;`. Therefore the {{hmtl}} could not decode it correctly

Answer: set the  `<json:object  escapeXml="false">` this meant that by the time it reaches client side it was in the correct format `&#39;` to be decoded by the jquery {{html }} tag.